# Determine root cause of java out of memory error

Tags: java

I am getting a websphere error..on further research it was mentioned that it was due of Java Out of memory. I am not familiar with JAva Heap and GC. I just modified few classes of code for an enhancement.  This applicaiton had no issues until now. Therefore I am leaning towards the modified code is causing issues.

How do I determine which object(s) is causing the oom error.

Comment: You can determine it by taking a look at the stacktrace java prints when it goes out of memory.

Comment: Sometimes, if it so happens that it crashes on the allocation of the objects that cause the problem. Otherwise, get a heap dump and use MAT on it to see where the memory is going (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Answer (score 0):

check if u  made recursively call for any method or infinite loop without any break otherwise you should share your code to let us able to help you

Comment: This answer is wrong. If the OP made an infinite recursion it would have fired a `StackOverflowError`, not a `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 0):

Post the error message. It could be you have to increase the heap size (using `-Xmx xxxx` flag) because the application just needs some more memory than it used to (for whatever reason noone can tell by the information you have given). You could also use `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a heap dump and thread dump when ever oom error occur 
it help to find the rca for this

Increse your jvm heap size as Xms as 512 and Xmx 1024